# Помогите понять как работает код(из learn.javascript)

Tags: javascript

> Создайте функцию isEmpty(obj), которая возвращает true, если в объекте нет свойств и false – если хоть одно свойство есть.

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  /* ваш код */
}

var schedule = {};

alert( isEmpty(schedule) ); 

schedule["8:30"] = "подъём";

alert( isEmpty(schedule) );
```

Вот ответ

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for(var key in obj){
    return false;
  };
  return true;
}
```

Почему перебор вызван для obj но переберает ассоциативный массив schedule?

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for(var key in schedule){
    return false;
  };
  return true;
}

var sss = {};
var schedule = {};

alert(isEmpty(schedule)); // true
alert(isEmpty(sss)); // true

schedule["8:30"] = "подъём";

alert(isEmpty(schedule)); // false
alert(isEmpty(sss)); // false
```

Comment: Эм, это ж функция, которой в первом аргументе obj передают объект schedule. Вы не знаете как работают функции что ли?

Comment: @andreymal почему тогда не вызвать перебор так? for(var key in schedule)

Comment: @kkkkkkkk потому что тогда функция сможет работать только с объектом shedule. В общем-то так работают функции, которые выполняют действия с глобальными переменными. Собственно, такая функция нужна только для того, чтобы выделить кусок кода, дать ему название и переложить в другое место. Функции, принимающие параметр могут использоваться много раз для разных переменных. Это намного полезнее и безопаснее. Хотя конечно в данном искусственном примере толку с аргументов никакого. Тут в принципе можно вообще без ф-ии обойтись)

Comment: Но если мы захотим проверить 3 массива: shedule1, shedule2 и shedule3, то от функции, принимающей аргумент толк будет. Мы просто вызовем isEmpty 3 раза: isEmpty(schedule1); isEmpty(schedule2); isEmpty(schedule3);.  И вместо аргумента obj будет каждый раз подставляться новый ассоциативный массив.

Comment: @YuryPlinto Посмотрите выше, я добавил код, он выдает то, что выдает, хотя в sss ничего не записывалось, значит должно быть true true но выводит true false

Comment: @kkkkkkkk ну всё правильно. Вы ведь написали в теле функции for (var key in shedule). Значит функция работает не с аргументом obj, а с глобальной переменной shedule. Перебор надо делать для аргумента obj

Comment: т.е. Вы передали в функцию аргумент obj, но никак его не используете))

Answer (score 2):

isEmpty функция которую ниже вызывают (в алертах) для массива schedule

Comment: почему тогда не вызвать перебор так? for(var key in schedule)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что в объектах можно задавать свойства через квадратные скобки, просто этот синтаксис похож на то, как задаются значения в массивах.

```
var obj = {};
obj.id = 5;
obj["id"] = 5; // то же самое
```

И да, в javascript объекты это и есть ассоциативные массивы, смотрим тут - https://learn.javascript.ru/object